# Does Ansible create a separate SSH Connection for each tasks inside a playbook

Tags: ssh, ansible

If I have multiple tasks defined in my playbook, does ansible creates a separate ssh connection for each of the tasks. If yes, is that not a performance issue.

Because whenever I do a verbose o/p while i run the playbook, against each task i spot this.
"ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: gparasha"
Am i wrong in my understanding.

Answer (score 13):

By default, Ansible creates a new connection for each task.  It takes advantage of [SSH connection multiplexing](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Multiplexing) to significantly reduce the amount of time required to establish a new connection.

If you enable the [pipelining](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#ansible-pipelining) feature, then in many cases Ansible will be able to re-use a single ssh connection for multiple tasks (although in some cases it will still need to spawn a new connection).

To enable pipelining, you need the following in your `ansible.cfg`:

```
[ssh_connection]
pipelining = True
```

Comment: Enabling pipelining is going to significantly speed up Ansible, especially for playbooks with many short tasks. The reason why it isn't enabled by default is because it only works if the `requiretty` option is not enabled in /etc/sudoers on all managed hosts, which means that for most distros you'd have to disable it, but for RHEL derivatives it's already disabled by default. It's pretty safe to disable `requiretty` as it doesn't provide a large security boost in the first place because an attacker can probably work around it.